# Can bookmarklets be used with the url Data:// instead of Javascript://

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

I'm having the problem of my bookmarklets not working because the url Javascript:// is blocked on my computer and was wondering if I can use the url Data:// instead

I've tried going into the site settings and other settings but it didn't help and then I figured the url Data:// would work but it brough me to a black screen with the code on it when I clicekd the bookmarklet.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Malware_and_phishing): some browsers now block webpages from navigating to data URIs.